# Google Sheets change value of text in a cell using Query?

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to be able to change the value of cell, from a number to text - but I'm not sure how to do it?

I have two tabs, `Source` and `Heath Hill`.

`Heath Hill` uses `Query` to pull in specific cells from the `source` tab. Here's my formula:

```
=QUERY(Source!$1:$1000,"select A,AB, D,F where C = 'Heath Hill'",1)
```

Columns `C` and `D` in `Heath Hill` are numbers, I'd like to be able to replace them with text.

**Column C**

- Replace any number `1` with `Business Interest`
- Replace any number `2` with `Representing an interest group`
- Replace any number `3` with `Profession`

**Column D**

- Replace any number `1` with `Agree`
- Replace any number `2` with `Disagree`
- Replace any number `3` with `Don't know`

Here's a [link to my example Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vEvkVGJTE560EJPb7IGCgfZpffRQFKbNEP9AcpNtbJI/edit?usp=sharing) I've simplified it.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

To achive what you are aiming here you will need to use an [**if** function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en).

The formulas you would need to use are as follow:

For column C : `=IF(C2=1,"Business Interest",IF(C2=2,"Representing an interest group","Profession"))`

For column D : `=IF(C2=1,"Agree",IF(C2=2,"Disagree","Don't know"))`

Here is an example of this implementation. I have created a new column for making it easier to visualise and the I just dragged and dropped to include all the values.

[image]

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use App Script instead

```
function UpdateReplace() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Sheet ID');
  var doc = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet_Name');
  var range = doc.getRange("C2:C");  
  var data  = range.getValues();
  for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace('1', 'Business Interest');
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace('2', 'Representing an interest group');
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace('3', 'Profession');
    }
  }
 range.setValues(data);
 Var range1 = doc.getRange("D2:D");
 ​Var data1 = range1.getValues();
  for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
 data1[row][col] = (data1[row][col]).toString().replace('1', 'Agree');
 data1[row][col] = (data1[row][col]).toString().replace('2', 'Disagree');
 data1[row][col] = (data1[row][col]).toString().replace('2', 'Don't know'); 
    }
  }
  range1.setValues(data1);
};
```